# SQL Query help finding missing pair

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a database table that keeps friendship requests.  What I need to do is find missing pairs.  The example would be as such:

A Proper value would be

```
Friend A > Friend B 
AND
Friend B > Friend A
```

What I want to do is find the missing partnership.  So if you have `Friend A > Friend B`, and the opposite is missing.  I want to list the ones missing.

I cannot for the life of me wrap around my head the best way to accomplish this.  Any suggestions?

Comment: what is your query right now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
SELECT MIN(user_id) user_id,
       MIN(friend_id) friend_id
  FROM Table1
 GROUP BY LEAST(user_id, friend_id),
          GREATEST(user_id, friend_id)
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Given sample data

```
| USER_ID | FRIEND_ID |
|---------|-----------|
|       1 |         2 |
|       2 |         1 |
|       1 |         3 |
|       2 |         4 |
|       5 |         6 |
|       6 |         5 |
```

Output of the query

```
| USER_ID | FRIEND_ID |
|---------|-----------|
|       1 |         3 |
|       2 |         4 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84195/1)** demo

Comment: your answers are always perfect..:)

Comment: @Sonali I'm not sure about that but thank you :) There are plenty of decorated experts here...

Comment: @BossRyan Did it help to solve your problem? Do you need more help with your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `not exists` clause:

```
select f.B as A, f.A as B
from friends f
where not exists (select 1
                  from friends f2
                  where f2.A = f.B and f2.B = f.A
                 );
```

The `select` clause gives you the ones that are missing.  Personally, I would just do `select f.*` to get the unmatched friends.